# What's the deal with NTFS tags in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, ntfs, tags

So back in the days of 'longhorn' there was this WinFS idea which was both cool looking and scary looking. Then it seemed to disappear, but we were told that many of the concepts would be rolled into Vista. Then maybe Win7. Anyway, nowadays if you look at a win7 Explorer window, you can have columns that have a lot of tag-based info about a file (right click on column header->more...), including one called "tags".

Is this something in NTFS that can be modified per-file somehow? Is its GUI hiding, or is this something that's infinitely-delayed, or is it just a figment of my imagination? Sure would be nice to be able to get around the NTFS path 256 character limit for searches, and to filter file folders per Excel 2007.

Comment: The 256 character limit is Win32 API, _not_ NTFS.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some info on modifying those properties

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Add-tags-or-other-properties-to-a-file
([Archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20160203222721/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Add-tags-or-other-properties-to-a-file))

and some info on how to utilize those properties:

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/micham/file-properties-in-windows-vista)

Comment: file properties has nothing to do with NTFS. It's the metadata inside the files